# What is the solution for "The Type or namespace 'AjaxControlToolkit' could not be found..."?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, database, textbox

```
 Error 3 The type or namespace name 'AjaxControlToolkit' could not be found
 in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)   
 D:\My App\table\PopUpdata.aspx.designer.cs 58 27 table.
```

I have Declared this javascript but what is the problem.

```
<%@ Page Title="Show Data From Menu" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="PopUpdata.aspx.cs" Inherits="table.PopUpdata" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

Comment: Right click on project and add reference and find ajax.dll

Comment: Check the name `AjaxControlToolKit` in the reference tab in the solution explorer

Comment: Add AjaxControlToolkit.dll in your project references

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Way to reference a `dll` is:

1. In Solution Explorer, select the project.
2. On the Project menu, click Add Reference.
      The Add Reference dialog box opens.
3. Select the tab indicating the type of component you want to reference.
      (If you don't find your .dll in the list, then go to the browse tab and find it in your directory)

An [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwawt96c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on **MSDN** to include installed libraries.

And there is [another way](https://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/GetFile.aspx?Page=act&File=AddToolbox.gif) to do it, too.

Answer (score 7):

To have the needed references for AjaxControlToolkit

**Right Click project/solution > Manage NuGet Packages..> Install AjaxControlToolkit.**

This will add needed assemblies to your solution.

Comment: I had it. But I needed to uninstall and reinstall again to make it work.

Comment: Yes Make sure you are running VS as Admin

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an assembly reference. So you need to reference AjaxControlToolkit.dll in your project.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue. I have deleted all the files from the bin folder and then added the files back to the folder. It worked successfully. Hope it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is general issue of dll

for solving this you must have 3 dll in your Bin folder

1--AjaxControlToolkit.dll

2--AjaxControlToolkit.dll.refresh   (Refresh file)

3--AjaxControlToolkit (Program Debug database)

[image]

Now just add the AjaxControlToolkit.dll refrence in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Add `AjaxControlToolkit.dll` in your bin folder and then clean solution and rebuild your solution