# ASP .NET Help Using AJAX - Global Namespace Not Found

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I've been having  a lot of projects with my ASP application. I'm using AJAX and yet I've been getting errors when uploading my app to my site:

> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the
>   LoaderExceptions property for more information.

It was recommended to downgrade AJAX to an earlier version. After removing the old AJAX .dll and adding the older version Im now getting these errors

> Error 26  The type or namespace name 'AjaxControlToolkit' could not be
>   found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)

I'm using .NET4.5 and the AJAX  is referenced as so in the header of my pages:

```
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>
```

Can someone please help me get this working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the solution for "The Type or namespace 'AjaxControlToolkit' could not be found..."?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393080/what-is-the-solution-for-the-type-or-namespace-ajaxcontroltoolkit-could-not-b)

Comment: check your dll in Bin folder where it is present or not

Comment: The .dll is definitely in the bin folder
I have followed the steps outlined in the line but it didn't work for me (I used that method to add the dll originally and it still caused me problems)