# The type or namespace name 'AjaxControlToolKit' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am currently working on Asp.Net with `AjaxControlToolkit`
I have search many articles regarding this, but couldn't find a proper answer.
I have even gave a  reference by right clicking on BIN Folder to the `AjaxControlToolKit.dll` where is saved and in my project's bin folder there is  `AjaxControlToolKit.dll` and `Ajaxmin.dll` but problem still persists.

How to solve this problem? Can any one help please?
Thank you in advance !

Comment: Have you rebuilt your project ?

Comment: Try cleaning solution and Rebuild solution

Comment: @MairajAhmad :Sir i have rebuild project many times even build another project and implement ajaxtoolkitcontrol in single webform but problem not yet solve

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the solution for "The Type or namespace 'AjaxControlToolkit' could not be found..."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393080/what-is-the-solution-for-the-type-or-namespace-ajaxcontroltoolkit-could-not-b)

Answer (score 2):

For the latest version of Ajax Control Toolkit. The spelling for the dll has changed. The reference now shows the name as "AjaxControlToolkit" (with the "K" in toolkit in lower case instead of upper case). Changing the case helped me to stop receiving a compile error for my web site.